# Django is complex select query possible for this?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model used to store a bidirectional relationship between two users. The records are always inserted where the smaller user id is user_a while the larger user id is user_b.

Is there a way to retrieve all records belonging to a reference user and the correct value of the status (apply negative transformation to relationship_type if user_a) based on whether the reference user id is larger or smaller than the other user id?

Perhaps two separate queries, one where reference user = user_a and another where reference user = user_b, followed by a join?

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    RELATIONSHIP_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Blocked'),
        (1, 'Allowed'),
        (-2, 'Pending_A'),
        (2, 'Pending_B'),
        (-3, 'Blocked_A'),
        (3, 'Blocked_B'),
    )
    user_a = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='user_a',null=True)
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='user_b',null=True)
    relationship_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_CHOICES, default=0)
```

A SQL query of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
(SELECT user_b as user_select, -relationship_type as type_select WHERE user_a='reference_user') UNION (SELECT user_a as user_select, relationship_type as type_select WHERE user_b='reference_user')
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what the input/output is here? You have a `user` and you want all `Relationship`s that belong to `user` through `user_a` *or* `user_b`?

Comment: The input is a reference user object that could be in either user_a or user_b. This is the easy part. However, the relationship_type field stores the directional relationship based on which user is in user_a's field so I need to do a transformation for the relationship_type value if the reference user is in user_b's field instead.

Comment: but you thus have as input a relation type as well?

Comment: At the present moment I would just need to retrieve all types. However, a method to select based on certain types would be nice for future reference if possible.

Comment: but given you want to retrieve all types, I do not really see what the relevance of the `relationship_type` is here then?

Comment: I need to transform all relationship_type such that they are standardised as though the reference user was in the user_a field even if it was stored as user_b (invert the result if user_b). i.e. Pending_A and Pending_B would be transformed to Pending_ReferenceUser and Pending_SelectedUser. Hope I am making it clearer here.

Comment: this looks more like a task for some sort of "proxy object", not the model itself.

Comment: If I could do something like (SELECT user_b as user_select, -relationship_type as type_select WHERE user_a='reference_user') UNION (SELECT user_a as user_select, relationship_type as type_select WHERE user_b='reference_user') that would more or less serve the purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have the id of the user `user_id`, you can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Relationship.objects.filter(Q(user_a_id=user_id) | Q(user_b_id=user_id))
```

If you have a `CustomUser` object `user`, it is almost the same:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Relationship.objects.filter(Q(user_a=user) | Q(user_b=user))
```

If you are looking to obtain `Relationship`s with a given type, we can do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Q

rel_type = 2  # example rel_type

Relationship.objects.filter(
    Q(user_a=user, relationship_type=rel_type) |
    Q(user_b=user, relationship_type=-rel_type)
)
```

Here we thus retrieve `Relationship` objects with `user_a` the given user and `relationship_type=2`, or `Relationship` objects with `user_b` the given user, and `relationship_type=-2`.

We could annotate the querysets, and then take the union, like:

```
qs1 = Relationship.objects.filter(
    user_a=user, relationship_type=rel_type
).annotate(
    user_select=F('user_b'),
    rel_type=F('relationship_type')
)

qs2 = Relationship.objects.filter(
    user_a=user, relationship_type=rel_type
).annotate(
    user_select=F('user_a'),
    rel_type=-F('relationship_type')
)

qs = qs1.union(qs2)
```

Although I do not know if that is a good idea: the annotations are not "writable" (so you can not update these).

It might be better to implement some sort of "proxy object" that can swap `user_a` and `user_b`, and negate the `relationship` type, and thus is able to act as if it is a real `Relationship` object.

Comment: Is there more overhead using a proxy object than transforming the relationship with annotations both on the read/write side?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, id in `user_a` is always smaller than `user_b`. So if you query with `user_b=user` then you should always get the references where `user_id` in the reference is always higher than other `user_id`. So I think you can use following querysets:

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=1)
user_a_references = Relationship.objects.filter(user_a=user)
user_b_references = Relationship.objects.filter(user_b=user)

all_relation_ships = user_a_reference.union(user_b_references)
```

Comment: Is there a way to hit the database only once with the query? Also, I'd like to transform the negative value to positive if reference user is user_a

Comment: @Joshua: here there are two queries: one to retrieve the `CustomUser`, and one to to obtain the relationships. Querysets are lazy, so `user_a_references` is never retrieved itself. If you have the `CustomUser` already, you thus can ignore the first query.